# trigger my code when a email is added to mailbox?

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Is there a way to triiger c# code when a email appears in a exchange mailbox ? The mailbox belongs to a servcie account.
I am flexible about using Azure, on a IAAS solution. Thanks,PEter

Comment: Did you check out EWS managed API? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj220535(v=exchg.80).aspx

Comment: so that link is from 2014. I am looking for something more current. what do you think aobut this approach  : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/webhooks   ?